# Word Label Merge with QR encoded data has wrapping data on last row of 1st and subsequent pages

Tags: merge, ms-word, qr-code

I have a word document that grabs data from an excel spreadsheet.  One of the fields is a QR encoded bar code.  I am merging it into labels in ms word.  I cannot figure out why starting with the last row of labels on the 1st page and subsequent pages the bar code shows up larger.  See image.[image]

Comment: I figured it out.  The data on those with large bar codes was longer than the first couple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data was longer on the larger bar codes.